# Error "provided statistics stream is corrupt" on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, indexing

I've got an error "provided statistics stream is corrupt" on SQL Server 2005. Is there any root cause for this error? Really appreciate for any comment in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do when you got this error?

Comment: Try to run `DBCC CHECKDB('databasename') WITH DATA_PURITY`

Comment: Are you running `create statistics ... with stats_stream`? And if so why?

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be in the damaged statistics, and probably in the one that was created automatically.

To search for problem statistics you can use:

```
EXEC sp_updatestats
```

EXEC will iterate over all the tables and statistics, and if there are problems, it will show which statistics, more precisely the table, is the problem.

To remove auto_created statistics, you can use the following script:

```
select 'drop statistics [' + OBJECT_NAME (OBJECT_ID) + '].[' + Name + ']' from sys.stats where auto_created = 1 and OBJECT_NAME (OBJECT_ID) = 'DB PROBLEM TABLE NAME'
```

The script will generate rows for deleting auto_created statistics for the table `DB PROBLEM TABLE NAME` table.

After running the generated lines, rerun the following to check for errors:

```
EXEC sp_updatestats
```

Not superfluous would be:

```
exec sp_msforeachtable N'UPDATE STATISTICS? WITH FULLSCAN'
```